# How to migrate using request library for a POST request to Axios?

Tags: api, post, request, axios, migrate

I've been grinding this out for awhile but am definitely hard blocked. I want to migrate my program from a deprecated request library to a different one. I chose axios but can't get it to work. All I need to be able to do is make the post request in a similar way that lets me access the response body.

Here is my **working deprecated library** request code:

```
const getPage = (apiUrl, size, stagedDateAfter) => {
let options = {
    json: true,
    body: {
        "summary": false,
        "sort": [{"stagedDate": "asc"}],
        "search_after": [stagedDateAfter],
        "queries": [],
        "page": {"max": size}
    }
};

request.post(apiUrl, options, (error, res, body) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }

    if (!error && res.statusCode === 200 && keepGoing == true) {
        if(body.meta.total == 0 || (!body)){
            throw("error");
        }

        /*
        Code works from this point, can access body, data, etc
        */
}
}
```

My **failing axios library** code:

```
function checkResponseStatus(res) {
    if(res.statusCode === 200 && keepGoing == true) {
        return res 
    } else {
        throw new Error(`The HTTP status of the reponse: ${res.status} (${res.statusText})`);
    }
}
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

const getPage = (apiUrl, size, stagedDateAfter) => {
    let options = {
        json: true,
        body: {
            "summary": false,
            "sort": [{"stagedDate": "asc"}],
            "search_after": [stagedDateAfter],
            "queries": [],
            "page": {"max": size}
        }
    };

    axios.post(apiUrl, options, headers)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
         if(!response){
             checkResponseStatus(response);
         }
         return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.res)
    })
     .then(data => {  //This code doesn't work since response not defined here
         if(response.data.status == 200){
             console.log(data);
         }
     });
```

All I need is to **be able to access the response body** using axios similarly to how I did with the request library but I'm reading the documentation, api, etc and I just cant seem to get the exact format right.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Correct format that lets me access body properly.

```
let options = {
        url: stringURL,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            "summary": false,
            "sort": [{"stagedDate": "asc"}],
            "search_after": [stagedDateAfter],
            "queries": [],
            "page": {"max": size}
        }
    };

        axios(options)
        .then((response)=>{
        //rest of code
```